# React setstate with datamaps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [Datamaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) for this example. I have a Datamap that, when clicked in `.datamaps-subunit.MI`, changes the color of the portion. I would also like to store a number into my React state. However, the code below results in a `this.setState is not a function` error.

```
lemap:function(){
    var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('maincontains'),
        scope: 'usa',
        fills: {defaultFill: 'rgb(217, 217, 217)'},
        done: function(datamap) {
            datamap.svg.select('.datamaps-subunit.MI').on('click', function(geography) {
                var m = {};
                var bis = this;
                m[geography.id] = 'pink';
                datamap.updateChoropleth(m);
                this.setState({trumpnum: 12});
            });
        }
    }); 
},
```

Comment: I believe this error is due to 'this' not pointing to react object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding `var sting = this` right beneath the function.

```
lemap:function(){
var sting = this;
    var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('maincontains'),
        scope: 'usa',
        fills: {defaultFill: 'rgb(217, 217, 217)'},
        done: function(datamap) {
            datamap.svg.select('.datamaps-subunit.MI').on('click', function(geography) {
                var m = {};
                var bis = this;
                m[geography.id] = 'pink';
                datamap.updateChoropleth(m);
                sting.setState({trumpnum: 12});
            });
        }
    }); 
},
```